# Unable to upload file on server using PHP file upload?

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I am unable to upload a file using PHP file upload to server. When we are trying to upload the same locally on the server using same PHP file upload page, it loaded successfully. But when we are trying to access from other system on the network using the same php page and upload the same file it shows below mention error.

```
include("connect.php");
$fname=$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
$sessionUsercode=$_SESSION['sessionUsercode'];
      $path="/home/path/to/upload/";
if(substr($fname,0,1)=="a")
{
    if(substr($fname,2,3)=="off")
    {
         $mmsg=ucwords("officers");
         $mside="A";
         $mcause="O";
    }
    else
    {
         $mmsg=ucwords("daily");
         $mside="A";
         $mcause="D";
    }
} else if(substr($fname,0,1)=="l")
{
         $mmsg=ucwords("Supplementary");
         $mside="A";
         $mcause="D";
}

echo "path". $lfname=$path.$fname;
echo $uploadfile=$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
if(!file_exists($uploadfile))
  $msg=ucwords("uploaded file doesn't exists!");
else
{
  $msize=filesize($uploadfile);
  if($msize>0)
  {
   if(file_exists($lfname))
     unlink($lfname);

  echo $res=copy($uploadfile,$lfname);

   if(!$res)
     $msg=ucwords("can't upload/copy said file!");
   else
   {
    $file_size=filesize($uploadfile);
    $handle = fopen($uploadfile,"r");

    $buffer = fread($handle, filesize($uploadfile));
    $buffer = addslashes($buffer);
    fclose($handle);


    $ent_dt=date("Y-m-d");
    $ent_tm=date("H:i:s");

    $rs1=mysql_query($sqlchk) or die(mysql_error());
    $nmsqlchk=mysql_num_rows($rs1);

   }

  }
  else
   $msg=ucwords("uploaded file is empty!");
}
header("Location:message.php?msg=$msg");
```

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlPCS.jpg)

Comment: show your code, how anybody justify the problem.

Comment: `Please help ASAP` this makes me wanna help you less.

Comment: Check webserver logfiles, this error is not PHP related

Answer (score 0):

i think this webserver error for  ipblock .u can change unblockip this working fine

Comment: Some files are uploaded successfully, but some are not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   

//include 'db.php';

extract($_POST);

extract($_POST);
if(isset($submit)) {
    $fname = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size =  $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];        
    $target = "img/".$fname;
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$target);
    echo "uploaded succ !"."<br>";
}
```